# svn2git with --exclude, any way to ignore the empty/blank commits?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm converting a big SVN repository into multiple git repositories (one for each project).

I am running svn2git for each repo with all unwanted directories `--exclude`d this works well to keep the tags and branches (I delete all the unrelated tags & branches after the conversion)

The only problem is I have loads of empty commits (commits relating to the excluded directories).

Is there any way to exclude these empty commits during the svn2git process?

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324799/git-remove-commits-with-empty-changeset-using-filter-branch/5324929#5324929) is a fine way to remove them after the fact, but `filter-branch` only affects the current branch, and not all the other branches and tags.

Comment: you can use `git filter-branch … --all` to filter all branches and tags

Comment: you're right, I'll give that a try. I'm very interested to know if there is a way to do this in svn2git during that process though. Everything seems cleaner when you get it right the first time, rather than rewriting the history afterwards.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Worked it out.

To the best of my knowledge, this command will rewrite the history, removing the blank commits, but preserving everything else.

`git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat --prune-empty -- --all`

You can use this command to query the number of commits before and after as a quick test:

`git log --pretty=format:'' | wc -l`

Comment: This worked, but left an empty initial commit - any idea on how to also filter that?

Comment: filter-branch works great, but `wc` has missed one commit. You should use `git rev-list --count @` to count commits.