# How to delete a directory and also the commit history for that directory

Tags: git

So I've successfully deleted a directory and its history from git.

With something like:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch folder-to-delete" HEAD
```

However, my git commit log still contains the commits for that directory. When I look at my repository history I see all the commits for those directories. They have no files in them (as expected), but the commits are still in the history.

Is it possible to delete these commits from the history as well?

Comment: [This](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-4.html), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37219/how-do-you-remove-a-specific-revision-in-the-git-history) might help.

Comment: I've already done all that... now I've got a bunch of orphaned commits in my commit log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `--prune-empty` switch on `git filter-branch` to remove now-empty commits from your history.

([Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324799/git-remove-commits-with-empty-changeset-using-filter-branch))