# How to clean git log when removing unwanted files with BFG Repo-Cleaner

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

I am trying to clean up a git repository by removing a number of files and folders with the easy to use BFG Repo-Cleaner. It removes the files and folders well (Thanks!) But the git log now has a number of commits with no file changes.

**How can I also update the history so that commits made empty by file removal are removed?**

Additional notes:

- This is possible with the more awkward `filter-branch` approaches (e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23188613/1224158)) with the `--prune-empty` option as described in [github's how-to](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/).
- The approach of cleaning all empty commits (e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5324916/1224158)) after the fact did't work well because: (a) there are some legitimate no-file commits in the repo left from old SVN tags, and (b) doing so also seems to strand some branches.

Comment: Thanks for those links; that solved my problem!